# How can I get the return value of /bin/ls -R if I run it using execl()?

Tags: c, linux, parent-child

So I have an assignment for Uni, in Linux C. The program has to call a child process, that has to run the `/bin/ls -R` command, then write out the return value in the parent process, that can't be 0. So far I could only get it working using the `system()` call, but I can't use that. The `wait(&value)` line works with the `system()` function, but not with `execl`. The code I've come up with so far:

```
int main(){
    int value=0;
    if(fork() == 0){
        printf("Running command, please wait..\n");
        sleep(2);
        char *path = "/bin/ls";
        char *arg1 = "-R";
        execl(path, arg1, NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    wait(&value); 
    printf("\nProcessing return value, please wait..\n");
    sleep(2);
    printf("\nThe return value of the child: %d \n", value); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "write out the return value in the parent process"? Do you want the return value of executing `ls` command or the output of the `ls` to be printed by the parent process?

Comment: Don't forget that by convention, the first argument to `execl` after the path should be the program's name (so that it gets `argv[0]` set to its name, as it expects).  You probably want `execl(path, path, arg1, (char *)NULL);`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the return value of /bin/ls -R if I run it using execl()?

If you `wait()` correctly (see bottom of my answer) then you *are* getting the return value of `/bin/ls -R`.

> that can't be 0

Not sure what you mean by this, but an exit status of `0` means that the process exited correctly. Something different than `0` means an error occurred, so you usually want things to exit with `0`, not something else.

The `exec*()` family of functions does not return when the execution succeeds. [Read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) to know more.

If you want the child to fail then pass an invalid path to `execl` to make it fail or just `return 1` straight away. In order to make `ls -R` return something different than `0` you might want to pass a third argument to `execl()` pointing to a path to which you do not have access to, like for example `/root`.

---

I am also not entirely sure what's wrong about your code, since it compiles and works correctly on my machine, *but*, here's some rules of thumb to follow both to find the problem and to avoid it in the first place:

1. Always read the manual (in this case [`man 2 wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html)):

   ```
   If  wstatus  is  not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in the int to which it points.  This
   integer can be inspected with the following macros (which take the integer  itself  as  an  argument,  not  a
   pointer to it, as is done in wait() and waitpid()!):

   WIFEXITED(wstatus)
         returns  true if the child terminated normally, that is, by calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by return‐
         ing from main().

   WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)
         returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the least significant 8  bits  of  the  status
         argument  that  the  child  specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument for a return
         statement in main().  This macro should be employed only if WIFEXITED returned true.
   ```
2. Always check for errors on functions that might fail. Hint: basically 99% of syscalls can fail, `fork` and `wait` are some of those.

   ```
   pid_t child_pid = fork();
   if (child_pid == -1) {
       perror("fork() failed");
       return 1;
   }

   // ...

   pid_t res = wait(&child_status);
   if (res != child_pid) {
       perror("wait() failed");
       return 1;
   }
   ```
3. Always compile enabling warnings: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Applying the above rules is most of the times all you need to figure out what's the problem. Here's a working version of your program after applying them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
    pid_t child_pid, res;
    int child_status;

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == -1) {
        perror("fork() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if(child_pid == 0) {
        sleep(123);
        execl("/bin/ls", "-R", NULL);
        perror("execl() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    res = wait(&child_status);
    if (res != child_pid) {
        perror("wait() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (WIFEXITED(child_status))
        printf("Child exited with status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(child_status));
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(child_status))
        printf("Child killed by signal %d.\n", WTERMSIG(child_status));
    else {
        puts("This should never happen! Something's really wrong.");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me better understand these functions, and for the code which is way more "safe". But for me, the code still returns 0 as status. This is correct, but I need a return value that is not 0. This is the problem I couldn't solve, how should I get the return value out of execl().

Comment: The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred. The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.

Comment: @BakosDominik as CRM pointed out, the `exec*()` family of functions does not return when the execution succeeds. [Read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) to know more. Also, why do you want the child to return something different from `0`? See the top of my updated answer. If you want the child to fail then just pass an invalid path to `execl` or just `return 1` straight away.